# Why isn't my code to fill a dictionary(and tableview) working?

Tags: ios, dictionary

When my iOs app is loaded, it is checked if it's the application's first load, and if so sets the default cells for a tableview. However, the code doesn't work.

In my view did load:

```
NSDictionary *dict;

//if the app HASN'T loaded before
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasLoaded"])
{
    //note that the app has loaded
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasLoaded"];

    //set the defaults

    //value1
    [dict setValue:@"some string" forKey:@"one"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:dict forKey:@"tableCells"];
}

//now add all to the table view
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tableCells"] allKeys] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

What I'm trying to do is, when my app loads for the first time, set some defaults with an associated value. However, when I log the dictionary's keys by using NSLog(@"%@", [dict allKeys]), immediately after setting the keys, I get null.

EDIT 1: Tried some of the answers, and now I'm getting something when I use NSLog, however my tableview isn't being populated.

EDIT 2: all is working, thanks!

Comment: If you have problems with tableView, post the related code.

Comment: @etolstoy what do you mean? I have as far as I'm concerned (bottom line).

Comment: Well, in order to get your tableView working, you must implement UITableViewDelegate methods, such as numberOfRows and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Oh... I don't know too much yet, I've just been trying to move from static cells (set in the storyboard, for which I had to delete some methods from the code) to values loaded from defaults. I'll read up a bit more

Comment: Yes, read some tutorials about UITableViews. You can close this question for now and mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `setObject:` instead of `setValue:`

```
[dict setObject:@"some string" forKey:@"one"];
```

And don't forget to call:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Thanks to @Bruno's comment about `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're never creating the `NSDictionary`, so `dict` is going to be null.

Comment: And it must be a NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created an instance of dict.  Try

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```